# How to get Navigation Menu List with SQL Query in ORACLE APEX?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to get this navigation list with query like "Select * from APEX_APPLICATION_MENU" I Don't know exact table for navigation menu

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to query `apex_application_list_entries`, e.g.

```
select entry_text 
from apex_application_list_entries
where application_id = 120;
```

For more info & research:

- go to App. Builder
- go to Utilities
- pick **Application Express Views**

  - check what's being offered

Comment: Thanks Its Working... :-)